# kivymd MDDialog does not show Items when OneLineListItem is specified

Tags: python-3.x, kivymd

I need to get a kivymd MDDialig dialog box with a list. When setting the type parameter to MDDialog by default or "custom", it displays only the title of the dialog box, but not the items themselves. Setting the type parameter to "simple" causes an error.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

main = '''

AnchorLayout:
    padding: "25sp"
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "top"
    TwoLineListItem:
        text: 'key'
        secondary_text: 'value_1'
        on_press: app.open_dialog()
'''

class Example(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(main)
    
    def open_dialog(self):
        dialog = MDDialog(
            title="key",
            items=[
                OneLineListItem(text="value_1"),
                OneLineListItem(text="value_2")
            ]
        )
        dialog.open()

Example().run()
```

When setting type to "simple" an error occurs

```
File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 961, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
KeyError: '\_left_container'

File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

An example of using the widget was taken from the kivyMD documentation. The buttons display correctly, but the elements do not. Any hints will help.

Below is an image that shows the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxyN5.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarListItem

KV = '''
<Item>

    ImageLeftWidget:
        source: root.source


MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_simple_dialog()
'''


class Item(OneLineAvatarListItem):
    divider = None
    source = StringProperty()


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None

def build(self):
    self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
    self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

def show_simple_dialog(self):
    if not self.dialog:
        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Set backup account",
            type="simple",
            items=[
                Item(text="user01@gmail.com", source="kivymd/images/logo/kivymd-icon-128.png"),
                Item(text="user02@gmail.com", source="data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png"),
            ],
        )
    self.dialog.open()


Example().run()
```

https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.1/components/dialog/#kivymd.uix.dialog.dialog.MDDialog.items

Comment: This example does not work for OneLineListItem.
I get an error

   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'